# Scale along the x axis

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I would like draw a line graph on my Website with Angular and Chart.js.
The special thing I would like do is to slide the complete graph along the x axis.

*(for example: x-axis = 13:00 , 14:00 , 15:00 , ... then i would hover and push with the left on my mouse to move the chart to: 15:00 , 16:00 , 17:00)
The Array with the right values for the whole "time" is already in data
(I would only move the sector)*

```
drawChart() {
this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: this.EnergyTimeArray,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'ABCDE',
        data: this.actArray,
        borderColor: '#7cb342',
        fill: '1'
      },
      {
        label: 'FGHIJK',
        data: this.testArray,
        borderColor: 'orange',
        fill: '-1'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Uhrzeit'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'YAxis'
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

[my Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jiG1.png)

....and now i would move the graph so that i can see the next times from 23:00 , 24:00 , ..

Do you have any solution for me? I can't find anything on the documentation.

Thanks Robin

Comment: could you post your code of your chart or a fiddle please

Comment: I dont think that such a behavior is indended. Whats about x-achse scrollbar?